# Codable synthesis for structs with array members not working?

Tags: swift

I'm surprised that something as simple as this doesn't compile (under Xcode 10):

```
protocol Foo: Codable {}

struct Bar: Codable {
    let foos: [Foo]
}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
Type 'Bar' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
Type 'Bar' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

Shouldn't these be automatically synthesized for such a simple case?  Why doesn't this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)

Comment: Foo is itself codable Protocol so bar doesn't understand how to decode & enocde its value. If you replace Foo with String it will compile fine